# Is there anyway to detect beginning of voice using microsoft azure speech cognitive sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

I am using  **"microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.32.0"** library for STT feature.
I want to detect if user talks again within 2-3 seconds after previous STT finished.
Right now I am using **recognizeOnceAsync** function.
It seems that it is only possible to get STT result after the voice ended, but not possible to detect beginning of voice.
Is there any way to do this ? Or a roundabout way?

Comment: I tried to listen **ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech** but it never triggered.

Comment: can you update your question with your code and config? 
Do you want to increase the waiting time before the process is stopped?

Comment: hi, I think the problem can be solved using **SpeechServiceConnection_EndSilenceTimeoutMs**.
But I want to know the default value of this and how to control this using javascript.

Comment: `speechConfig.setProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_EndSilenceTimeoutMs, "4000");`
This code seems to be not working. No changes whether we set or not.
@RishabhM

Comment: What error you're getting with above code?

Comment: Have you tried with SetProperty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256081/discussion-between-rishabhm-and-acedev).

Answer (score 1):

To handle silence and configure timeout you can check **Segmentation silence timeout** property that can help in make results longer and allow longer pauses from the speaker within a phrase.

The default value is **500** and can be adjust in range of 100 to 5000 in milliseconds.

```
speechConfig.SetProperty(PropertyId.Speech_SegmentationSilenceTimeoutMs, "2000");
```

For more details regarding silence handling, you can check this  [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp#change-how-silence-is-handled)

An alternative approach could be to utilize `continuous recognition` instead of single-shot recognition, which provides more control over when to cease recognition. For more information and examples, please refer to the provided [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-python#use-continuous-recognition)

Comment: I think we should set **Speech_EndSilenceTimeoutMs** as well?
The main idea is to increase STT delay to prevent the user input is **cut**. @RishabhM

Comment: Based on your scenario, the segmentation silence can prevent the user input cutoff by extending the silence period in between the input phrases.

Comment: what is **Speech_EndSilenceTimeoutMs** then?

Comment: It seems the `EndSilenceTimeout Property` is helpful in case of ambiguous phrases.
You can check the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.endsilencetimeout?view=netframework-4.8.1#remarks). The default value is 150ms and range from 0 to 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Based on package name, it looks like you are using CognitiveServices Speech SDK for JavaScript.
The earliest information about recognized speech you can get by checking the intermediate results (recognizing event), see the following sample how to use the recognizing event in JavaScript.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/node/speech.js

Comment: great. I will check.